# FileHelpers delete list/reset

Tags: c#, .net, windows, filehelpers

I am developing a test application using C# and .NET. I am a programmer (embedded) but I am not very familiar with this environment.
I have made an application that collects sensor data from an Arduino and uses FileHelpers API to populate a list of data for exporting to CSV.

```
        // Initializing Log generation
    FileHelperEngine<logItems> engine = new FileHelperEngine<logItems>();
    List<logItems> logItems = new List<logItems>();
```

And the log save event

```
        private void stopButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrGUI.Enabled = false; // Stop sampling

        double maxValue = pressureTable.Max();
        PeakValueIndicator.Text = maxValue.ToString("0.00");
        engine.HeaderText = "Sample,Pressure,Time";
        engine.WriteFile(string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"), "_", TestNameControl.Text, ".csv"), logItems);
        logGenerator();

        TestNameControl.Text = string.Empty;
        startButton.Enabled = false;
        stopButton.Enabled = false;
```

The application works, however if I run the data collection more than one time without closing the program between runs it will append the new sensor data at the end of the previous data list.
Is there a way to reset the list either by using the FileHelpers API or memory resetting the list using regular C#?

Comment: Do you want to clear the list before you "do data collection", or after you write it out to disk? Anyway, write `logItems.Clear();` at the point you want to discard old log items.

Comment: `WriteFile` doesn't append, it overwrites, so as gnud says, it's likely to be your list management that needs looking at.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I fixed it by using `logItems.Clear();` as per your suggestions. Thank you